# Why i can not change text view value in fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm new to android, I wrote a simple app to learn `fragments`. I created a text view:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/behzad"
        android:text="behzad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

In fragment I wrote this simple method:

```
public void setTest(){

        TextView text=(TextView) FiveView.findViewById(R.id.behzad);
        text.setText("hahaha");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I call that method in activity:

```
Fragment frag=adapter.getItem(4);
        ((FiveFragment)frag).setTest();
```

I get the `ok` message from toast but the fragment's text view does not show `hahaha`

Why the text view's value has not changed? This is my [code](https://codeshare.io/aYWA7Q)

Comment: your textview in which layout?

Comment: @Vij my text view in FiveFragment layout

Comment: Who down vote me! i say beginner!

Comment: is there your fragment being called ?

Comment: Use TextView text=(TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.behzad); instead

Comment: @UsmanRana my friend in my question FiveView=getView

Comment: Please include your whole Fragment class

Comment: @PERSISTENCE please review my post,end line my fragment five code link

Comment: @PERSISTENCE can you find my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear your `setTest()` method in `onCreate()` and move it to  `onCreateView()`.

Comment: setTest not in onCreate! into class FiveFragment!

Comment: Just move your `setTest()` method inside `onCreateView()`

Comment: when move that setTest method into onCreateView get '; excepted error'

Comment: Add a semicolon just like this `setTest();` then run it.

Comment: public void setTest();{... --->so get semicolon except error

Comment: Why are you adding access modifiers inside a method? Just copy this `setTest();` and paste it inside `onCreateView()`

Comment: thats work ,but when i try call in button fire dont work!

Comment: Just call the `setTest()` method in your `onClickListener()`. Please accept my answer

Comment: my friend i say when try to call setTest method in onClickListener my code dont work

Comment: write this code for call that and dont comment:Fragment frag=adapter.getItem(4);
        ((FiveFragment)frag).setTest();

Comment: Do you have teamviewer?

Answer (score 0):

add notifyDataSetChanged() in your code:

```
Fragment frag=adapter.getItem(4);
        ((FiveFragment)frag).setTest();
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Fragment fragment = adapter.getItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    if (fragment instanceof FiveFragment) {
               fragment.setTest();
            }
```

Comment: my freind i want when user fire a button ,in activity call one method on the fragment 5 and that change text view,your solution run just one way,maybe user click 5 on button.

Comment: @stackstack textview is on Activity or Fragment?

Comment: textView on the Fragment

Comment: @stackstack and button on Activity?

Answer (score 0):

Make your TextView object static and try again.

Comment: Try to make FiveView static.

Comment: Please post whole source code of your Fragment here.

Comment: can you find my problem?

Answer (score 0):

In Your Fragment I hope you called your setText() method in onCreateView method of Your Fragment

In your Activity

```
Your_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
 public void onClick(View v){
    Your_Fragment fragmentObject = new Fragment();
    fragmentObject.setTest();
 }
}
```

I hope this will work